# Is a merge supposed to be able to yield the Necromancy badge?

Tags: bug, badges, merged-questions, necromancer-badge

I'm pretty sure that when I posted [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/39153/991), the question was very different and fairly recent, which makes me suspect a [merger](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merged-questions). ​ However, I just got [the Necromancer badge](//crypto.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer?userid=991) for that answer.

Is the Necromancer badge supposed to be given when an answer "with score of 5 or more"

gets merged from a recent question to a question that is "more than 60 days" old?

Comment: Merge indeed, as can be seen in the revisions: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/24623/revisions

Comment: That has the answer, even though the is attributing mine to the older question. ​ ​